# vb.net checking process is ended, and modify the UI

Tags: vb.net, forms, process, program-entry-point

I have a problem, my program (when launched the process) minimized into system tray, and when the process ended, it shows in normal state, but its not working with my solution, I get this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

My code:

```
Dim p as new Process
p.filename = "somefile.exe"
p.workingdirectory = "somepath"
p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
AddHandler p.Exited, AddressOf Main.Main_Process_Closed
p.Start()
```

The handler in the main form:

```
Public Sub Main_Process_Closed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Visible = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

But what is the problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a handler, it is possible that the handler is going to be invoked by a secondary thread other than the UI thread.  As such, you do not have the ability to directly manipulate the UI thread.

You will need to use Invoke to properly marshal to the UI thread.  Here is a great [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that should walk you through it.